# Simple javascript drawing app (with mouse) issues (problems with mouse positions being undefined)

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

```
    if(spacepress==false){ //before space bar is pressed (space bar = allows fox movement)
        function init(){ //INITIALIZATION
        c.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        }

        function mouseDown(event) { //MOUSE DOWN
            drag = true;
            draw(getMousePos.x, getMousePos.y, false);
        }

        function mouseUp(){ //MOUSE UP
            drag = false;
        }

        function getMousePos() { //get MOUSE x,y POSITION
            rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
              x: event.clientX - rect.left,
              y: event.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }

        function mouseMove(){ //MOUSE MOVE
            if(drag){
                draw(getMousePos.x, getMousePos.y, true);
                console.log(getMousePos.x); //SHOWS UNDEFINED, think this is the issue
            }
        }

        function draw(x,y,drag){ //DRAWING
            if (drag){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#537c38";
                ctx.lineWidth = 20;
                ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
                ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
        }
    init();
    }
```

I'm very new when it comes to javascript so this might be some very rookie mistake, this is a simple drawing app I want to insert in one of my games that I have to do for school project but I'm having issues that I don't know how to solve, if you have any solutions please if possible explain them in noob-friendly way since I probably won't understand any advance solutions to this problem. I'm almost positive issue is at getMousePos() function (maybe there's more than 1 issue, not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the "event" variable inside getMousePos is undefined because getMousePos does not "see" it. You have to give "event" as a paremeter to getMousePos. This is an example of how to pass the "event" and use it inside your function :

```
function mouseDown(event) { //MOUSE DOWN
  drag = true;
  var coords = getMousePos(event);
  draw(coords.x, coords.y, false);
}

function getMousePos(event) { //get MOUSE x,y POSITION
  rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: event.clientX - rect.left,
    y: event.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

Same thing you have to do in your other cases in which you need to calculate mouse position after a function has been called because of mouse event.